# Django: How to match null in database

Tags: django, django-models

By using django ORM: How to match the result in database is NOT null?

```
example_objects = Example.objects.filter(field !=null)
```

I'm not sure about how to write that filter to get all non-null records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for either:

```
Example.objects.filter(field__isnull=False)
```

or:

```
Example.objects.exclude(field__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
example_objects = Example.objects.exclude(field=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

`example_objects = Example.objects.exclude(field =null)`?

Answer (score -1):

Use NullBooleanFeild as below::

```
happy = models.NullBooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
```