# how do I search null or none in mongoengine in my django work?

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

there is a field in my mongodb, i want to search the field, no matter this field is None or not, how do i search?
for example:`Robot.objects(data_set_id=None)`
i use this to search ,but get the error:
bson.errors.InvalidId: 'None' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string

Comment: in fact ,I use Q object, q = Q(
        name=name,
        customer=customer_id,
        type=Robot.TYPE_VARIABLE_BLOCK,
        trashed__ne=True,
        data_set_id=data_set_id,
    )

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTIONS THAT DON'T WORK FOR ME:**

**1. Using `__isnull` or `__eq` -> FAILED**

```py
Robot.objects.filter(data_set_id__isnull=True)
Robot.objects.filter(data_set_id__eq=None)
# Cannot resolve subfield or operator isnull on the field data_set_id
```

**2. Using `Q` alone or combine with `__isnull` or `__eq` -> FAILED**

```py
from mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q
Robot.objects.filter(Q(data_set_id=None))
# 'None' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string
```

---

**SOLUTIONS THAT WORK FOR ME:**

**3. Using `__raw__`**

```py
Robot.objects.(__raw__={"data_set_id":None}))
```

**4. Updating `pymongo` version to the latest one**

```
- pymongo==3.12.3
+ pymongo==3.13.0
```

But if you are using `mongomock`, you need to update DB connection like this

```py
mongo_client_class = pymongo.MongoClient

if mongodb_uri.startswith("mongomock://"):
    mongodb_uri = "mongodb://localhost"
    import mongomock
    mongo_client_class = mongomock.MongoClient

connect(host=mongodb_uri, mongo_client_class=mongo_client_class)
```

However, after the fix, you can still face another issue of `mongomock` where inserting duplicate documents (violates unique contrainsts in model classes) is not caught & rejected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all objects witch `data_set_id` field contain a null value:

```
Robot.objects.filter(data_set_id__isnull=True)
```

Comment: InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve subfield or operator isnull on the field data_set_id

Answer (score 0):

Checking value of a field agains `null` returns:

- documents without the field, and
- documents in which the field exists and its value is `null`.

Please note it is `mongoengine`, therefore `__isnull` (mentioned in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4293993/5515472)) does not work.

Below query returns documents with their field equals `null` (excludes the first group):

```py
from mongoengine.queryset.visitor import Q

MongoEngineModel.objects(Q(fieldName=None) & Q(fieldName__exists=True))
```